# Strange bash errors when passing script to ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to run a local script remotely that I'm calling with some other code. The basic formate is

```
ssh -i ${PemKey} ${User}@${URL} 'bash -s' -- < ${Command}
```

I get the error line `24: ${Command}: ambiguous redirect`
Command is a string with the name of the script I want to run and its arguments. If I change the script to just print the command as

```
echo "ssh -i ${PemKey} ${User}@${URL} 'bash -s' -- < ${Command}"
```

and then run the command myself it works just fine.
I've tried putting the command in a temp variable and then call it that way, like:

```
TEMP="ssh -i ${PemKey} ${User}@${URL} 'bash -s' -- < ${Command}"
$TEMP
echo $TEMP
```

This results in `No such file or directory`. Again the echoed version of the command runs just fine at the command line.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, this works for me: `echo pwd | ssh localhost bash -s`

Comment: This also works: `ssh localhost bash -s <<< pwd`. But this doesn't: `ssh localhost bash -s < pwd`.

Comment: Use double quotes around `"${Command}"` (and all your other variables). Also, don't copy-paste parts of error messages: e.g. `bash: : No such file or directory` tells you way more than just the human readable text.

Comment: Gaah, I had quotes around the string in my Command variable so hadn't put them around it the way you have it. Moving them fixes everything, thanks. If you want to post that as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Actually no... that gets ride of the ambiguous redirect error but again triggers the file not found dir because it looks for the script on the remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that executing `$TEMP` doesn't work correctly, as the whole string `'bash -s' -- < ${Command}` is given in argument to `ssh`. And in fact if you create a file called `${Command}` on you remote host you will get an error `bash: bash -s: command not found`.

A solution is to uses `eval` like this :

```
eval $TEMP
```

This really does what it should.